# Почему "старая перечница"?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Оскорбительно-пренебрежительный термин для пожилой женщины — "старая перечница".
А почему именно перечница, а не, скажем, солонка или сахарница?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Есть объяснение, основанное на этимологии.
"Старая перечница" = пожилая регистраторша. В русском языке есть два паронима — регистр и реестр, которые на русский переводятся как ПЕРЕЧЕНЬ, список.
Налоговый регистр, реестр платёжных поручений — слова пришли через разные языки в разное время. От регистра — регистратор и регистраторша (разг.), профессия того, кто что-то регистрирует, составляет списки. Чаще всего это были пожилые женщины, не очень приятные в общении, по крайней мере в худ. произведениях герои их часто проклинают, их трудно уговорить. Вот она и есть перечница (от "перечень" — "регистр").
Очень эмоциональное обзывание, совпадающее по смыслу с образом растрескавшейся перечницы для перца и производным от "перечить".

Comment: Надо же! Мне тоже всегда было интересно, почему "перечница", а оказывается, вот оно как! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

а может, она сначала была поперЕчница? ну, старые люди любят стоять на своём, спорят и настаивают на своей правоте...потом стала перЕчница, ну, а народная этимология перевела в пЕречницу, включив, скорее всего, оттенок недоброжелательности в оценке личности..ведь милую бабулю назовут, скорее, одуванчиком))

Answer (score 1):

Здесь имеется в виду "острая на язык", поэтому  именно перечница.

В "Алисе..." Кэрролла еще обыгрываются значения "перец-перечить", но последнее слово к перцу никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Обыгрываются слова скорей не у Кэролла, а в переводе Бориса Заходера.

Comment: Скорее всего. Я в оригинале не читала.

Answer (score 1):

Известный филолог и писатель Мария Васильевна Семенова считает это выражение производным от глагола "перечить", что означало свойство охотничей собаки распутывать след зверя не с начала, а с конца, то есть, в обратную сторону. Поэтому и в выражении "старая перечница" речь идет не о перце или остром на язык человеке, а о свойстве делать что-то наоборот, неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще такой вариант:

Сначала был "старый перечник". Это - буквальный перевод немецкого выражения «Der Alte peppermann», возникло в Германии еще во второй половине XVI века. В те времена так прозвали солдат-отставников, без семьи и родных и вынужденных зарабаты­вать на жизнь торговлей пряностями и мелкой галантереей.

Поскольку они были всегда готовы по­живиться за чужой счет или поухаживать за замужней женщиной, это название быс­тро приобрело неодобрительный смысл. В XVIII веке оно появилось и в России, правда, уже как прозвище. Слово было похоже на исконно рус­ское «перечник», проис­ходящее от глагола «перечить» — возражать. Так словосочетание «старый перечник» при­обрело новое значение и стало означать пожилого одинокого человека, с неуживчивым характером, или по-простому «старый ворчун». 
Затем возникло выражение "старая перечница" - это пожилая женщина, также с неуживчивым нравом, острая на язык. Её нельзя обвинить в излишнем гуманизме.
Не песок из неё сыплется, а острый перец.

https://otvet.mail.ru/question/96502556

Answer (score 0):

Андерсен в сказке *"Ночной колпак старого холостяка"* рассказывает о том, откуда произошло выражение "перечный молодец". Может быть оттуда пошло?

*"Перец являлся главным предметом торговли, оттого и немецких приказчиков прозвали в Дании перечными молодцами. Хозяева брали с них обязательство не жениться на чужбине, они и не женились, доживали до старости холостяками."*

Вполне вероятно, что со временем выражение прижилось в обращении и к женскому, и к мужскому роду.

Старая перечница  / перечный молодец - человек, доживший до старости холостяком.

Answer (score -1):

Если буквально переводить слово «пеппербокс» с английского языка, получится «ящик с перцем», или «перечница». Это слово применялось на первых порах к любым многозарядным пистолетам – даже к обыкновенным одноствольным револьверам. Но прижилось оно именно в отношении исторических чудовищ, напоминающих то ли огромный револьвер, то ли маленький пулемет.
Отсюда http://warfiles.ru/show-32651-staraya-perechnica-ruchnoe-strelkovoe-oruzhie.html .
Так что этимология может быть и другой - эта дама - заряженный пистолет, пусть и старый. ;)

Comment: Увы, это догадки, не имеющие рационального подтверждения. Чтобы оно появилось, надо хотя бы примерно объяснить, как могло перенестись английское название оружия на русский эпитет пожилой женщины. Тут одного перевода мало, надо еще и ситуацию проанализировать.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?